# Add power regression trendline programatically to a chart via Visual Studio Tools for Office

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

After searching through ther internet, I cannot get the  right path to be able to plot a trendline (power regression one) programatically with a chart designed in C#.

For the Moment I have :

```
        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

        chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("mydata");
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter;
//Add a PowerRegression Line to the Chart
```

I beleive the only way to do it is do it by hand ( or better use the linear regression tool of Excel (which is accessible from C#) with **log(data)** and then plot it on the chart). 
Any Alternatives?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trendline from vsto like this:

```
Excel.Series series = chart.SeriesCollection(1);
Excel.Trendlines trendlines = series.Trendlines();
tl.Add(Excel.XlTrendlineType.xlPower);
```

This adds a trendline to the first series of the chart. Here are all the possible trendline types from which you can choose: [Trendline types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xltrendlinetype%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

If you would want to do a trendline that is not supported you would need to calculate the points for it and just add it as a standalone series to the chart - like you already mentioned.